# Can you change IE document mode using Selenium WebDriver and C#?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using WebDriver and Selenium Server 2.28. I'm running this on a Windows 7 environment, and the version of IE is 9.0.8.

I'd like to know if there is any way of forcing compatibility mode in IE using Selenium 2. I've googled this, and there doesn't seem to be a lot of information about this.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the properties and forcing IE to open in Compatibility mode until you are finished testing? You'll need to run as Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Without further details it is hard to give specific details, but you can force IE into a specific compatibility mode using a special `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

A value of `EmulateIE7` will tell IE to evaluate the `<!doctype>` as if it'd be IE7. Other valid values would be `IE7`, `IE8`, `IE9`, or `Edge`, which will use the specific version's behavior.

Just keep in mind that the differences implied by this aren't necessarily 100% the same as when using the specific browser versions (but it should be very close especially regarding JavaScript/DOM and HTML).